# LSTM Class Imbalance

Tags: many-to-many, conv-neural-network, lstm

**TLDR**

Extract features using CNN, feed into a separate many to many LSTM model. Binary classification but ratio of class 1 to class 2 is 1:4 resulting in overfitting during training.

From what I understand, if I remove class 2 data such that ratio is now 1:1, shuffle the data with the labels so the model is not guessing class 1 for the first half of the samples, I will be ruining the temporal sequence of the data. The model will not be able to make good predictions based on the adjacent frames.

How can I solve this?

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

The idea is to create a Flappy Bird bot that takes in a sequence of 5 images and predicts whether to jump or not. To achieve this, I have taken as input 20 000 images of gameplay at around 10 fps and extracted the features from the Flatten() layer of the following architecture.

Input: `(samples, height, width, channels)` in other words `(20 000, 250, 150, 3)`

Features: `(20 000, 14336)`

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(250,150,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(512, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(512, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.summary()

RMSprop = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop, metrics=['accuracy'])

callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.0001, mode='max', patience=10)]
```

I then reshaped the features to `(4 000, 5, 14336)` where 5 is my time_step. I also reshaped my labels to `(4 000, 5, 2)` where jump and not jump are one-hot encoded. I then took the features as input to the many to many LSTM.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(5, 14336), dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

RMSprop = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop, metrics=['accuracy'])

callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.0001, mode='max', patience=10)]
```

As expected, the model overfitted and I stopped the training:

```
Epoch 6/50
3232/3232 [==============================] - 138s 43ms/step - loss: 0.5020 - acc: 0.8058 - val_loss: 0.5541 - val_acc: 0.7735
```

As mentioned, I did consider balancing the classes and shuffling the data (both of which I have not done) as to my understanding this will mess up the sequence of images which would take away from the whole point of using LSTM.

I have tried using just a CNN trained on individual frames with a shuffle and balanced classes and that achieved a 0.9 val_acc and 0.95 acc which is pretty decent. However,  on testing the bot, it failed to last more than 6 seconds; its highscore was just 3.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a custom loss function where you weight your samples according to their population?

Comment: @SaTa No I have. Any tips as to creating one? Thanks for the suggestion; will google how to make one

Comment: You can also start by adjusting class_weight and sample_weight inputs of model.fit. It will be easier than writing a custom loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have closed this question and opened a more detailed one